# Mapbox Right Mouse Click

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm using the L.map contextmenu to listen for right clicks on the map. However, when I right click the map, in addition to the contextmenu event being fired, it also fires the mousedown event and the MouseEvent data does not indicate which mouse button was pressed, so the "left press" code is executed in addition to the "right press" code.  Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Tony

Answer (score 4):

If you want to listen to left click you must use the `click` event, if you want to listen for rightclick you must use the `contextmenu` event. The `mousedown` event fires on left and right click. It does exactly what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Hi iH8, I respectfully disagree.  I use mousedown in conjunction with mousemove and mouseup to handle my own drawing for selection of groups of markers, measuring distance by clicking multiple times, etc.  I cannot use click for my purpose.  It is common to expect to be able to determine which mouse button was pressed in the mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup events.  Even raw JavaScript will allow you to inspect the event.which to determine the mouse button pressed.

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to why you can't use the click event for your project. Perhaps you can give an example with code in your question so that we can understand? Sounds kind of hacky to me

Comment: When I capture Leaflet `mousedown` events on the map, I can see the `button` attribute of the `originalEvent` passed? What Leaflet version are you running?

Comment: I'm using Mapbox 2.2.2.  Snkashis, you are right, there is an originalEvent in the MouseEvent event data.  Sorry, I somehow missed this. iH8, an example is drawing a rectangle around a group of markers to select them.  I capture mousedown position, then with mousemove events (dragging of sorts) I draw the selection box, and in mouseup I finalize the selection by determining which markers are inside my selection rectangle.  Let me know if you would still like a code example.